# How do I configure IP forwarding on a Netgear N600 WNDR3400 router?

Tags: networking, router, virtual-machine, load-balancer

I've got a Netgear N600 WNDR3400 Router at home. Is it possible to create a virtual hostname on my home network and have it forward to specific IP addresses of my choosing?

For instance, I'd like to create a virtual host name like `http://router1`, and round-robin any connection to that name to a list of designated IPs.

I'm not sure if my router even supports it, my cable company gave it to me for free.

Comment: What is the actual model number? N600 is a classification of netgear routers which support 300Mbps on the 2.4Ghz range + 300Mbps on the 5Ghz range. The model will likely start with `WNDR`, probably `WNDR3400` or `WNDR3700`. That said, I don't believe Netgear's default firmware will support round-robin load balancing.

Comment: @SAFX - A Round Robin connection on a single internet connection within a private local network seems sort of pointless.  It serves no purpose, you can't generate enough traffic, to make it worth while.

Comment: @SAFX Ramhound is correct on that point as well. You'd want a reverse proxy load balancer, such as `nginx` to distribute HTTP requests evenly. DNS Round-robin does not distribute requests evenly, it only distributes computers evenly. You need a large volume of client computers for it to actually "balance".

Comment: @Ramhound I'm doing this for development purposes and I need to test real-world scenarios locally. DNS round-robin is enough for my objectives. I'm building a messaging app and I need to test middleware forwarding with well-known addresses (virtual ips) between message producers and consumers, so I have my reasons. Can I do simple IP forwarding with my router?

Comment: @SAFX - Most routers support port forwarding.  Check you router's manual on how to do it.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, my router supports port forwarding, but only to a single IP; I need multiple IP's in round robin fashion.

Comment: @SAFX - You have your answer.  You won't be able to round robin with the router in question if thats the case.

Answer (score 3):

The default Netgear firmware does not support DNS round-robin. Your best bet is to see if you can get DD-WRT up and running on the router as a replacement firmware. It allows much more control and a much greater featureset for many linux-based routers.

Most specifically, it comes with the ability to completely configure the DNS proxy (DNSmasq), and you can use this to set up a round-robin DNS entry for any clients that are using the router as a dns server.

---

First, turn on DNSMasq under Setup -> Basic Setup

[image: Enable DNSMasq]

Then add `host-record`s to DNSMasq's config on Services -> Services

[image: Add Host Records]

Here, I've bound `chat.test.com` to a round robin of `192.168.0.12`, `192.168.0.13`, and `192.168.0.14`.

Comment: I updated the answer with what I think you're looking for.

Comment: OK, tried this. In your example, does `test.com` need to be configured as the `LAN Domain`? My LAN domain is `home`, so I added host-record `host-record=route.home,192.168.1.201:8080`, tried w/o domain using `host-record=route,192.168.1.201:8080`, but neither worked. I added a static DHCP mapping for virtual host `route`, didn't work. Created new question, please post follow ups there, thx: http://superuser.com/q/596544/171942

Comment: It doesn't really matter what the LAN domain is, DNSMasq will let you override any domain: `host-record=google.com,192.168.0.13` should work just fine. You can test the results with `nslookup chat.test.com <routerip>`. I imagine yours didn't work because you added `:8080` - There is no port involved with this, it's just DNS. *All* ports will be redirected.