# DD-WRT, virtual hostname forwarding to other names/IP's using round robin

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, dd-wrt

I'm using DD-WRT v24/K2.6 on Netgear WNDR3400. On my home network I have many machines running (I do lots of distributed programming). I want to create a virtual hostname, say `publisher`, such that any requests on `tcp://publisher:5556` are forwarded, round-robin style, to a list of other host names on my home network.

Is this possible? I'm very new to DD-WRT, and with so many options, it's a bit overwhelming. If not possible, I plan to use HAProxy instead, but I'd rather do it in the router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dd-wrt is [built on Linux](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linux_Inside) so you could possibly compile a build with HAProxy built in. Looks like other have tried [this](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=725441) with nginx and Pound but run into issues:

> Don't set your expectations too high. Although it is working fine in
>   concept, preliminary testing shows it's a too heavy burden on the
>   MIPS-cpu.
>
> Discrete http-traffic is no problem, but when I was browsing my
>   photo-website whilst looking with top on my router, I saw nginx taking
>   up 98% of CPU and my hi-res photos were crawling.

My recommendation would be to get a mini PC (maybe something like [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16856205007)) and use that to do what you want.

Comment: You mean use the mini pc with HAProxy to do the forwarding?

Comment: Yes. Sounds like the performance might not be too great. Note that is an old thread and I haven't tried it. Also might be easier to get working.

Comment: I ended up taking your advice and installed HAProxy but on its own Linux server, great product, works just like a hardware load-balancer, plus I learned something new! thx, Brad!